# Can't pass data from attributes using ajax laravel 5.1

Tags: ajax

```
var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('name', name.val());
                formData.append('email', email.val());
                formData.append('contact_number', contact_number.val());
                formData.append('barangay', barangay.val());
                formData.append('landmark', landmark.val());
                formData.append('password', password.val());
                formData.append('confirm_password', confirm_password.val());
```

//Problem start here it came from attributes but I can alert the data and it was fine.

```
                formData.append('image_pin', img_top);
                formData.append('img_left', img_left);
                formData.append('img_z_index', img_z_index);
                formData.append('input_value', input_value);
                formData.append('input_top', input_top);
                formData.append('input_left', input_left);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'register',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.val() },
                method: 'post',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function(){

                } 
            });
```

//The input works fine but the attributes data is undefined

```
$request->input('img_top');
$request->input('img_left');
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `$('form').serialize()` to solve?

Comment: Thanks actually it works now. I didn't change anything, I was just so confuse yesterday. I forgot I didn't input anything on my image that's the reason. I tried your serialize and it works too.